Updating AG Grid from v29 to v31 - Angular
We're using ag-grid-angular and ag-grid-community version 29.1.0 and I need to update to the latest.
I've had a go using the codemods, and while that runs successfully, it doesn't modify any of the source files. I'm assuming this is down to the currrent partial support for Angular.
The main issue I'm having is with the deprecation of gridOptions.api and gridOptions.columnApi, which both link to this page.
The suggested approach seems incompatible with our project, as we don't use createGrid, but rather pass the grid options to the ag-grid-angular component.
Is there another means of obtaining a reference to the API?
Thanks

Your 2nd link goes to the docs for the "plain javascript" edition of AG-Grid. Here is the same page for the "Angular" edition: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-interface/#grid-api, this might help you better.
